# List item count is empty when there's only one item

Tags: 2010, powershell

I would like to iterate a list where the `Status` field is "new".
Relevant part of the code:

```
#load list
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
#get new items
$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Status'] -eq "New"}
write-host "Found " $spSourceItems.Count " new items"
```

Now, my problem is, that if there is only one match or no match at all, the `$spSourceItems.Count` is empty. If there's 2 or more match, it returns the correct value. Is this normal? How can I return 1 if there's only one new record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CAML` query to query the list items.

In CAML query, i am passing the internal name of the `Status` column

Try the below code:

```
#load list
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
#get new items
$spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$spqQuery.Query =  "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>New</Value></Eq></Where>" 

$splListItems = $spSourceList.GetItems($spqQuery)  

write-host "Found " $splListItems.Count " new items"
```

[How to do a CAML Query through PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-do-a-CAML-Query-6f5260cf)